# Create PDF using Node.js, Jade and Express

Tags: node.js, pdf, express, phantomjs, pug

I'm trying to create a PDF from one of my views.

This view is rendered using Jade and Express, loads some Javascript, some CSS files, extends some Jade views, and queries a database to populate different graphs. The rendering process takes about 7 seconds because it is not very well optimized.

Additionally, the GET request for the view uses `passport` and `connect-ensure-login` to verify that the user is logged in before rendering and passes some variables for Jade to use when rendering. This is the handler code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require('moment');

router.get('/', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(), function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('summary', {
        title: 'Summary',
        day: moment().format('D'),
        month: moment().locale('es').format('MMMM'),
        year: moment().format('YYYY')
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the Jade file that needs to be converted to PDF:

```
extends layout

block content

    .container-fluid

        #banner

        .chart#chart1
        .chart#chart2
        .chart#chart3

        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/summary.js')
```

And this is the Jade file (layout) that is extended:

```
doctype html

html
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
        meta(http-equiv='content-type', content='text/html; charset=UTF-8')
        meta(content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1', name='viewport')
        title=title

        link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/styles.css')

        script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/jquery-3.1.1/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js')

    body
        .page-wrapper
            block content
```

How would I go about loading the page and taking a screenshot and converting it to a PDF or rendering it as a PDF from the Jade file?

I've heard of PhantomJS but I can't find information that is up-to-date.

If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is use the jade/pug to generate the .html file with the desired values, save it in the File System (Async way)  once this is done, use this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

To Read (Async way) the .html file that you saved in the file system and convert it into a pdf, and finally, stream it to the client.

Maybe you can use another library to instead of write to the File System, pipe it directly to the PDF converter, and it will be faster.

If the template will change frequently, this will have to be done for every request, otherwise, you can cache it, and only generate it the first time, then detect if is already there and pipe it to the response.

Hope it helps.